# How to setup Backoff with Akkling?

Tags: f#, akka.net

When using Akka.net directly, I can do something like:

```
let superProps = Backoff.OnFailure(p, "supervised", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0), 0.2)
```

When I define the props using Akkling like this:

```
let p = props(actorOf2(fun a -> SomeActor.someBehavior foo bar a))
```

I get the error:

```
The type 'Props<obj>' is not compatible with the type 'Props'
```

So how to do this correctly with Akkling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akkling's `Props<>` type has `ToProps` method, which converts it into traditional Akka.NET `Props` type.